# JdbcTemplate vs JPA native query?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate

I really cannot understand what are the advantages of using the Jdbc template over the native queries.
For example the following query:

```
@Query(native=true, value="select ID from table")
public Integer native1();
```

is equivalent to:

```
int result = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(select ID from table", Integer.class);
```

But the first one seems more compact. Maybe the only usage I could think for jdbcTemplate would be to call a stored procedure...can someone help me to better understand?

Comment: JdbcTemplate can be used for dynamic query execution, Spring data native query is more static

Comment: Both will work fine. The question is how much control you want. Spring JDBC is a nice abstraction, but it’s closer to SQL, which means you’ll have more control but also a lot more boiler plate code to write.

Comment: Can I have an example of boilerplate? In the end they look symilar to me

Comment: How would you use batch operation on query? JdbcTemplate has Batch Operations